# Which line the program running on with a backtrace info?

Tags: linux, debugging, elf

there is my backtrace info:

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7bc07)[0x7f959bba4c07]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d23a)[0x7f959bba623a]
/lib64/libspice-server.so.1(+0x2108e)[0x7f959c8d508e]
/lib64/libspice-server.so.1(+0x227a3)[0x7f959c8d67a3]
/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm(qemu_iohandler_poll+0xc6)[0x7f95a10571e6]
/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm(main_loop_wait+0x188)[0x7f95a105b748]
/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm(main+0x1240)[0x7f95a0f7ce30]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f959bb4aaf5]
/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm(+0xb2ced)[0x7f95a0f80ced]
```

I create a kvm instance with spice, but it is crashed and I got this message from log.

Now, I want to know which line did I make it crash. But no link symbol table with `/lib64/libspice-server.so.1`.

I can get the address offset with `+0x2108e`. Any way to find out with line did it crash?

Btw, any tutorial with debug the library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Any way to find out with line did it crash?

Your `libc.so.6` and `libspice-server.so.1` are (apparently) fully-stripped.

You'll want to install `debuginfo` packages for both libraries, and then use `addr2line` to translate addresses to symbol/file/line, like so:

```
addr2line -fe /lib64/libc.so.6 0x7bc07 0x7d23a
```